# meaning difference between detail and specific

Tags: vocabulary

I'm confused about the words to detail and specific.

Can you tell me in detail?
Can you tell me specifically?

Can you be more detailed?
Can you be more specific?

What's the difference between them?

The dictionary says:

detail : including every part of something:
specific : exact or containing details

First, I'm wondering whether specific is used as the meaning
"exact" or "containing details" in "Can you tell me specifically?"

And If specific is used as the meaning "containing details",
I'm wondering if the meaning of "specific" and "in detail" is exactly the same.

Comment: Hello.  I expect you have checked a dictionary. (1) Please copy the dictionary defintion into your question.  (2) Please tell me why the dictionary defintion isn't clear.    https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/learner-english/detail    https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/learner-english/specific   The difference between these words is that they have different meanings.

Comment: @JamesK thank you I edited